# using SignalR in VS2010 with StartUp Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, signalr

I have a ASP.NET C# application.

I am targetting Framework 4.0.

I have this code:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using MyNameSpace;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyNameSpace.Startup))]
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

**The type or namespace name 'Owin' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

If i try to update using the nuGet package console I get this error message:

**Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin 3.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0',**

I have followed the advice to install a specific version of SignalR via the command line:

**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3**

I am wondering if I can do this using Framework 4.0.

I would love to upgrade to framework 4.5.x but the server is Windows Web Server and will only support VS2010 which is limited to Framework 4.0.

What are my options?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738034/the-type-or-namespace-iappbuilder-could-not-be-foundmissing-using-a-directive-p .  You can also look in your references folder to see what you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your code with these:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapHubs();
        }
    }
```

add the following on your `Global.asax`

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that is what I eventually did. But, as you are the only one who replied you get my 'tick' - thanks