# Getting an error message "IAppBuilder could not be found"

Tags: c#, owin

I am doing user authentication using owin middleware. But for IppBuilder it is giving error "IAppBuilder could not found. Are you missing Reference?" I have already installed nuggets packages related to owin as shown while searching on google.
Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using OpenConfigure.Core;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(CURDApis.API.Startup))]

namespace CURDApis.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738034/the-type-or-namespace-iappbuilder-could-not-be-foundmissing-using-a-directive-p ?

Comment: yes. I also tried this but did not work for me.  Thank you.

Comment: Problem is solved . I added reference of owin 1.0 to my project. Now working fine. Thank you.